# How disable encrypting password in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How disable encrypting password in devise?

Comment: why do you that. It's a big security issue if you do that. I hope it's not easy to do.

Comment: You might really want to expand on the why. If you want to do it for speeding up your tests for example you would decrease the security  of the encryption algorithm to speed up performance by adding "config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10" to the devise.rb in initializers. This line is included per default in newer versions of devise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Shingara. You should never store people's passwords in an manner that's recoverable devise stores passwords hashed (not encrypted), they're both unreadable formats, but the difference is that you can't reverse the hashing.

If you're wondering why, this is so that *if* your site or database gets compromised, the hackers won't be able to steal your users passwords (users have a bad habit of using the same password on almost every site). You don't want to look silly by not hashing passwords, and you've no excuse since it's provided free for you with devise.

The only thing you need to be able to do with a password is authorize a user, which can still be done with a hashed password. You never need to tell users their password if they forget it, instead reset their password to something new (devise supports this too).

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? Why is it an answer at all (and not a comment)? I am interested in the real answer because while developing the app I do not need to secure my test passwords.

Comment: Okay, if you don't need to secure passwords for a test or development system, just have them all use "test1" or some other sample password. Why go to the effort of disabling it (which isn't just a config switch) just because you don't need it?

Comment: @Jeremy What if you want to test updating/changing passwords, which is what I need to do right now...?

Comment: @Micah you can still update the password, test that the encrypted content is different that it was before, and then test that your new password authenticates. Generally, I wouldn't recommend doing that in a unit test. Devise will test that themselves, you should instead just have an integration test for your html interface that updates the password, then logs in again with the new password.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy for the reply. That makes sense, however my app is an API-only app, which serves json to an iOS client. That's why I'd like to have some type of test in the API app itself, to test the update password endpoint. Not a huge deal though.

Comment: @Micah That still applies, just your integration test will be sending the API request to change, then ensuring new password authenticates via the API

Answer (score 18):

DISCLAIMER: While it certainly is not generally wise to store passwords unencrypted, there could exist cases in which the developer would want to do this. Hopefully the developer is conscientious enough to make sure that in making this generally poor security decision for their app, they are not endangering personal and or identifying info of their users. You might imagine a case where the app's only logged information is user interaction with the system as in some kind of study of user interaction.

tl;dr One can disable encryption in devise by [creating a custom encryptor](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-a-custom-encryptor)
 and just having it return the password directly.

Comment: I personally believe this should be the correct answer.
It was not a question of ethics, or best practices... the question could not get ANY clearer... :D  Great answer, Michael.

Comment: In some apps users may not get to choose their own passwords (A simple example might be kids in school, using some webapp in the classroom). In these cases the password would likely be something like their student id, the intention not being to actually have any security, but just to validate that the student wishes to assume their identity in the system (maybe to load past work). In these instances, the database would only have some meaningless number, not the user's password on any other site, and very likely would not give away an email address either.

thanks Joshua