# How to print the user password in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In my controller

```
@user = User.last
```

In my view

```
<%= @user.password.inspect %>
```

returns nil value, but if i am using

```
<%= @user.encrypted_password.inspect %>
```

it shows `"$2a$11$LXD0UDB3kvwxqG/w/0icGuy6iXEOFZ264ushzSi6LfXSdAitwPmNO"`

How do I print the password instead of the encrypted password.

Comment: You can not get actual password text back from encrypted value instead you can cross check newly entered password against the encrypted password value.

Answer (score 2):

Passwords shouldn't be stored as plain text in database and the whole point of hashing them is that they are very hard (in terms of computation power) to reverse.

Assuming you are using Devise for authentication you can read [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#password=-instance_method) 
what `password` method do:

> Generates a hashed password based on the given value. For legacy reasons, we use `encrypted_password` to store the hashed password.

Its only responsibility is to set a password, not to return any value.

By looking at your `schema.rb` or commands like `User.column_names` you can see there is no such column as password in your database.

---

But If you really need to store passwords as plain text then according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12032073/9335023) you should write your own [encryptor method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-a-custom-encryptor)

---

If you are interested only in checking if particular password is same as the one stored in database then you can use [valid_password?](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#valid_password%3F-instance_method)

> Verifies whether a password (ie from sign in) is the user password.

like this:

```
@user = User.last 
@user.valid_password?('password')
```

Comment: then how to check the particular password is present in users table or not guys

Comment: @raja why do you want to check that?

Answer (score 0):

The whole concept of storing passwords in encrypted form is to maintain the security of the user information.

Moreover, you can match using

Bcrypt Calculator:

https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator.

If you are using devise then you can use recoverable module or the custom logic you have written to reset password.